# Explaining cat .git/config ouput for tracking remote branches?

Tags: git, github

I'm learning in my tutorial about git and it recently gave out the output for cat .git/config for tracking remote branches as seen below. I understand that branch "master" is the master branch and origin refers to the remote tracking branch in the local computer but can someone explain what the fetch, merge and remote options are (I understand the rest)?

```
   $ cat .git/config
    [core]
            repositoryformatversion = 0
            filemode = false
            bare = false
            logallrefupdates = true
            symlinks = false
            ignorecase = true
    [remote "origin"]
            url = https://github.com/rich44/explore_california.git
            fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [branch "master"]
            remote = origin
            merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, each of these is just a section with variables, so it's not really true that, e.g., `[branch "master"]` *is* the master branch, it's just a pair of settings that can be spelled out as:

```
branch.master.remote origin
branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Your question effectively works out to some number of parts, which I'll try to take in a sensible order, although Git being what it is, sometimes no order is sensible. :-)

## Configuration sections

Git likes<sup>1</sup> to talk about "sections" in the configuration.  Specifically, the `git config` command has `--rename-section` and `--remove-section`.  A *section* is basically just the part inside square brackets, which is a syntax stolen originally from [INI file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

Beyond this, however, Git internally doesn't actually care about sections.  Each program simply queries with either a fixed string, such as `core.bare` or `branch.master.remote`, or using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or similar, such as `core\..*`, which matches everything in the `[core]` section.  Here the backslash is required to protect the first dot `.` character; the second `.` character means "match anything" and the asterisk `*`—called a [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) in informatics theory—means "repeat it zero or more times".  Hence this matches any string starting with `core.` and continuing on for zero or more characters.  (Most of the C code inside Git that matches items in sections is considerably cruder than this; only `git config` itself and various scripts that run `git config` really use the full power of regular expressions.)

The ability to scan for matches allows Git to, for instance, find all *remotes*, which are simply all the names in each `[remote "..."]` section.  (The double quotes here evolved because INI-file syntax forbids certain characters that are allowed in remote names and branch names and so on.  Fortunately, remote and branch names cannot contain double quotes: if they could, we would have to wonder how these would be encoded.)

---

<sup>1</sup>I realize I'm [anthropomorphizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism) Git here.  It's a useful metaphor.  But remember, don't anthropomorphize computers: they hate that!

---

#### Items in a `remote "..."` section

Because INI syntax is so flexible, you can put anything you like into this section.  Things Git does not know or care about, Git simply ignores.  For instance, you can edit your config to contain:

```
[remote "origin"]
    abracadabra = magic word
    hello = kitty
```

and these two settings will be ignored.  So it's more interesting to find out what items Git will actually pay any attention to.  (Any list we make is necessarily incomplete, because Git grows new "items to pay attention to" over time: at one point, Git looked for `url` but not for `pushurl`.  At a previous $job, many years ago, I added code to our Git scripts to check for a `pushurl`.  Then a new version of Git, 1.6.4, came out, that used `pushurl` in precisely the same way I had used it.  [Clearly we had the same idea.]  If we choose our new items well, we'll probably end up agreeing with the Git folks as to their meanings, as happened here, but it's always a bit of a risk, adding new things.)

Nonetheless, here's a partial list, mostly copied from [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

- `url`: The default place to fetch from, and usually, to push to.
- `pushurl`: If set, the default place to push to.
- `mirror`: If set, make pushes to this remote use `--mirror` by default.
- `proxy`: Provide a proxy setting for libcurl.
- `fetch`: Provide a default refspec for `git fetch` (may be repeated).
- `push`: Provide a default refspec for `git push` (may be repeated).
- `prune`: If set, make fetch from this remote use `--prune` by default.

The one you specifically asked about—the `fetch` line—supplies *refspecs* for `git fetch`.  See below for more about refspecs.

#### Items in a `branch "..."` section

Again, there is quite a long list of things you can set that Git does actually pay attention to.  These are mostly, though perhaps never completely, documented in [that same `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

- `remote`: The default *remote* to use when fetching and pushing.
- `merge`: The name of the branch *as seen on the remote Git*, to use when fetching and pushing.  This gets a bit complicated in complicated cases: see the description of refspecs below.
- `rebase`: A setting (default `false`, other options include `true` and `preserve`) for how `git pull` should run its second half (remember that `git pull` is essentially shorthand for "first run `git fetch`, then run another, second, Git command").
- `description`: A short descriptive string inserted into `format-patch` cover letters and pull requests.

#### A thing to know about branch names

Git originally had branches and tags.  To keep them separate, Git stored branches in `refs/heads/` and tags in `refs/tags/`.  These were—and in fact, still are—just directories within `.git`, although today there are also "packed references" stored in `.git/packed-refs`, which saves time and disk space if you have thousands of rarely-updated branches and never-updated tags.

What this means, though, is that when you see a branch name like `master`, Git actually sees `refs/heads/master`.  This is not only where Git stores the hash ID for the branch, it's also how Git knows that it *is* a branch in the first place.  You type in `master`; Git searches in `.git/refs/` and `.git/packed-refs`, and comes up with `refs/heads/master`; and the `refs/heads/` part tells Git: aha, this is a *branch*!

When Git acquired *remote-tracking branches*, they were easy to add, because of this little bit of planning ahead.  A remote-tracking branch is simply a name stored in `refs/remotes/`.  To this prefix, Git adds the name of the remote itself, so that `origin/master` goes in `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  This full name is what tells Git that the name is in fact a remote-tracking branch in the first place.

#### refspecs

To really understand refspecs, it helps to know a bit of Git history.  Back in the Dim Time, *before Git had remotes and remote-tracking branches*, people had a collection of various [kludges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) to deal with pushing and pulling changes from other Git repositories.  There was a `git fetch` then, but it was a difficult-to-use "plumbing" program, meant mainly for scripts to use.  It dumped its results into a file called `FETCH_HEAD`.  The front end "nice" command was `git pull`.  This is why Git has `push` and `pull` as the obvious—but wrong!—opposites, and why people are usually introduced to transferring data with `push` and `pull` instead of using `push` and `fetch`, which is actually the better way to go at first.  The *nice* version of `fetch` did not exist yet.  Today's `git fetch` *still* dumps its results into `FETCH_HEAD`, but also behaves better.

Because remote-tracking branches did not exist, refspecs did not really need to exist then either.  If you were fetching from Bob's repository, you had a nicer front end script that ran `git fetch`.  The fetch reached into Bob's computer somehow (via `ssh` or `http` or `https` or whatever, just as is still done today) and extracted his branches and tags and dropped everything into your `FETCH_HEAD` file.  Your front-end script then extracted whatever looked interesting and let you merge, or rebase, or whatever you intended to do.

Note that during this process, you don't have to care one bit how Bob names his branches.  Your front end script just looks into `FETCH_HEAD`.  That file is completely separate from *your* branches, and you—or your front end script—can throw away Bob's branch names as soon as you are done looking.

Your nice front-end pull script, of course, *does* need to know Bob's name for your branch.  Let's say you call your branch `paris`, while Bob calls his `asteroid_433`.  You always want to merge his into yours, so you just configure your `branch.paris.merge` to `asteroid_433`.

This whole process was pretty messy.  Someone came along and invented *remote-tracking branches*, which really is quite a brilliant idea.  Instead of having to remember that Bob calls this `asteroid_433`, why not just get everything from Bob?  For each name you get, if it's a *branch*—if it starts with `refs/heads/`—just drop it into your repository under the name `refs/remotes/Bob/whatever`.  Now you can easily see *all* of Bob's branches any time.  You'll still need to remember the mapping ("my `paris` = Bob's `asteroid_433`") but *most* of the time you two will probably use the same name.

Imagine you're the guy inventing this wonderful new feature.  Of course, the `pull` script already exists.  You can't change `branch.paris.merge`: it's still going to say `refs/heads/asteroid_433`, which is the name on Bob's computer.  And, you're not sure if this is how you *want* to do it.  Maybe you'd like to have `git fetch` grab Bob's `asteroid_433` and *rename* it to `paris`, so that you get `refs/remotes/Bob/paris` as the remote-tracking branch.

Enter the refspec.<sup>2</sup>  The refspec is, in this case, simply a *pair of names* separated by a colon, and optionally prefixed with a plus sign.  The name on the left is the "source" and the name on the right is the "destination".  The source is Bob's names for his branches, and the destination is your remote-tracking branches for your remote named `bob`.

To make this work nicely, you put in pattern matching.  For whatever reason, you don't use regular expressions, but rather use shell style [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) expressions.  (In versions of Git before 2.9 or so these are even further limited.  They work well enough though.)  You still have the name on the left, `refs/heads/*`, and the name on the right, `refs/remotes/bob/*`, but now the left side `*` means "match anything", and the right side `*` means "replace this with what you matched on the left".

This produces your remote-tracking branches, which `git fetch` now updates.  To *store* your new refspecs, you add `fetch` configuration entries to the `[remote "bob"]` section.

To allow for multiple renamings, you make sure Git reads *all* the `fetch =` lines, so that someone can write:

```
[remote "bob"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/asteroid_433:refs/remotes/bob/paris
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/bob/master
```

and so on.  But in practice, most remotes ended up with just one `fetch` line.

(Allowing multiple lines is good forethought, as it turns out that today, we sometimes want to add refspecs beginning with `+refs/notes/...` so that we can bring over Git notes.  You can't know this yet, but obviously you're pretty smart, coming up with remote-tracking branches in the first place. :-) )

Of course, the old `branch.paris.merge` syntax has to stick around around, because you can't change existing Git users' configurations.  So now Git must, when it goes to use this `merge` value, *map* the value through the same `fetch` refspecs in order to figure out the correct remote-tracking branch name.  (The old pull script didn't bother—it just got the value from `FETCH_HEAD` directly.  That script has somewhat recently been rewritten as a C program, and it is no longer obvious what it does.  The `merge` and `rebase` commands, when run standalone, do in fact do this mapping, as they must.)

I should mention the leading `+` here as well.  This is simply the *force* flag for the given refspec.  It's the equivalent of `git push --force`: it means "this reference should be updated no matter what", as compared to the more usual rule for branch name updates, which are allowed if the update adds new commits, but rejected if the update would "lose" existing commits (e.g., if you're picking up an upstream `git reset` of some sort).  Normally every `fetch =` refspec for each remote has the leading `+`, since you always want all your remote-tracking branches updated to whatever commit *their* branch says is the correct one right now.

---

<sup>2</sup>Actually, it already existed, for `git push` purposes, because `git push` always needed it.  But it got refined somewhat.

Comment: awesome. another epic answer.

Comment: Great answer! I guess just for curiosity's sake, do you know why they call it merge to reference to a remote branch, rather than remote branch?

Comment: The original `pull` script would just merge the corresponding head. (Well, at the point where the config line happened, anyway.) The general "upstream" stuff all came later. So the name `merge` was just a poor choice made early on, from a *lack* of planning ahead.

Comment: I don't think many people would have been able to answer it. Wow thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Remotes are the remote repositories your local repository has information about, you can have your local repository point to multiple remote repositories, you can explore more using "git remote --help(also explore git remote add ...)". "Origin" is a remote repository which is created by default when you clone your local repository and it points to the repository you cloned your local repository from("git remote show origin" gives more information).

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The above tells you what branches in the remote named "origin" you would want to fetch the next time you execute "git fetch origin"

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The above tells "git pull" what branch merge the next time you execute the "git pull" command. In the above case it says to fetch the contents from origin repository. The information on what to fetch is gotten from "fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" as explained earlier. "merge = refs/heads/master" tells what remote branch to merge into your local once the fetch has been done, in the above example it tells to merge the remotes(origin) "master" into your local "master".